# Solve the problem with a specific limitation

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-theory, dijkstra

Assume that there are a set of roads that connect the cities between A and B. We model this as a graph of $n$ nodes (cities) connected by $m$ edges (roads). Each edge weight corresponds to the time it takes to travel along that road, so the edge weight for the road between city $u$ and the city $v$ is $w(u, v)$. There are two types of roads: free roads and roads with cost. All cost roads cost the same amount and are generally (although not always) faster than free roads. Bob would like to reach city B from A as fast as possible, however, he only has enough money to take at most one cost road.

**How to find such a route?**

Comment: The brief mention of "with a specific limitation" in the title is presumably hinting at having "enough money to take at most one cost road."  I recommend that you say whether you know how to solve problems without that limitation, which then sets up the existing Answer nicely (because it reduces the problem so solving ones that have no such limitation).

Answer (score 1):

First let's specify the problem in terms of directed graphs. If the original graph is undirected, simply double each edge and give them opposite directions.

One simple method is to have a graph that contains two copies `v'` and `v''` of each of the original vertex `v`.

If there is a *free* road between `u` and `v`, there are edges between `u'` and `v'`, and between `u''` and `v''`.

If there is a *toll* road between `u` and `v`, there is an edge between `u'` and `v''`.

You can visualise this as a graph with two floors. Each floor is a free part of the original grap, and there are one-way connections between the floors that correspond to toll roads (you can only go down but never up).

Also add edges between `A'` and `A''`, and `B'` and `B''`.

Now every path between `A'` and `B''` has no more than one toll road. You use any algorithm to find the shortest one.

This generalises to any number of toll road permissible on the route (have N+1 copies of the original graph).

Comment: For N toll roads allowed on the route, have N+1 floors and all possible ways down that correspond to toll roads. Finding all paths is infeasible. If you assign a very high length to each toll road (more than all other roads combined) then your pay will be minimised (you will take a toll road only when there is no other way).

Comment: Generalization:  Assume "time is money", i.e. cost = time_cost_factor * time and N tolls roads exist.  Create N+1 floors, and cost each link with toll cost +  time_cost_factor * time.  Dijkstra will optimize the the number of toll roads taken.

Comment: I am looking at a GENERALIZATION of the problem where time is money, the toll roads have different costs and time saving, and there is no artificial limit on the number of toll roads taken from those available.

Comment: @ravenspoint It is not a generalisation, it is a simplification. Just set the edge weight accordingly (time_cost_factor * time + toll). No need to create floors or alter topology in any way.